# Passport.js :Failed to serialize user into session(already added code for serialization)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am a newbie to nodejs and am trying to build a login system.I have added the code to serialize the user from passport documentation in **config/passport.js**.But still I am getting the error:Failed to serialize user into session when I enter a valid email and password to login.Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');


const app = express();

//Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

//DB config
require('dotenv').config(); //for setting environment variables on server
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri,{useNewUrlParser:true ,useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => console.log("mongodb connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));


//EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine','ejs');

//Express Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

//Express session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  }));

//Passport middleware for authentication and login   
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//connect flash
app.use(flash());

//global variables to create flash messages
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});

//Routes
app.use('/',require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users',require('./routes/users'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT,console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

**config/passport.js**

```
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

//load user model
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(
        new localStrategy({usernameField:'email'},(email,password,done) => {
            //Check if email is registered
            User.findOne({email:email})
                .then( user => {
                    if(!user){
                        return done(null,false,{message:'This email is not registered'});
                    }
                    //if email exists we compare password
                    bcrypt.compare(password,user.password,(err,isMatch) => {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        if(isMatch){
                            return done(null,true);
                        }
                        else{
                            return done(null,false,{message:'Wrong Password!'});
                        }
                    });
                }    
                )
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })
    );

    //Serialize and deserialize user

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
      });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
          done(err, user);
        });
      });
};
```

**routes/users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');

//Login page
router.get('/login',(req,res)=>res.render('login'));

//Register
router.get('/register',(req,res)=>res.render('register'));

//Registration Handling
router.post('/register',(req,res) =>{
    const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
    let errors = [];
    //Check required fields
    if(!name || !email ||!password  || !password2){
        errors.push({msg:'Please fill required fields'});
    }

    //check if passwords equal
    if(password !== password2){
        errors.push({msg:'Passwords do not match'});
    }

    //check password length
    if(password.length<6){
        errors.push({msg:'Password should be atleast 6 characters'});
    }

    if(errors.length>0){
        res.render('register',{
            errors,
            name,
            email,
            password,
            password2
        });
    }else{
        //Validation passed

        //check if email already exists
        User.findOne({email:email})
            .then(user => {
            if(user){
                errors.push({msg:'Email already registered'});
                res.render('register',{
                    errors,
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                    password2,
                });
            }
            else{
                const newUser = new User({
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                });

                //Hash password
                bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err,salt) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password,salt,(err,hash) => {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        //set password to hash
                        newUser.password = hash
                        //save user
                        newUser.save()
                            .then( user => {
                                req.flash('success_msg','Thanks for registering!You can login now');
                                res.redirect('/users/login');
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                console.log(err);
                            });
                    });
                });
            }

            });

    }
});

//Login handling
router.post('/login',(req,res,next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect:'/dashboard',
        failureRedirect:'/users/login', //these routes are wrt host
        failureFlash: true,
    })(req,res,next);
});

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1):

I passed the wrong argument to done() when the password was a match in **passport.js**.
I used

```
if(isMatch){
    return done(null,true);
}
```

where it should have been

```
if(isMatch){
    return done(null,user);
}
```